# Solving for unknown in combinatorics

Tags: combinatorics

I am working on a statistics problem wherein I need to solve for x that satisfies the following equation.

$\frac{{94 \choose x}}{100 \choose x} \leq 0.10$, where

${n \choose k}$ denotes choosing $k$ items from $n$ items.

Can I get some avenues or methods to solve such problems?  I cannot think of an approach even.

Comment: You might start by expressing the binomial coefficients using factorials. But in the end you'll evaluate this numerically.

Comment: Brute force: `which(choose(94,1:100)/choose(100,1:100)<=0.10)`  in R is one possible avenue

Comment: I suppose you want the **least** integer $x$ such that $\binom{100}x/\binom{94}x\le0.10$. One approach would be to calculate the partial products of the infinite product $$\frac{94}{100}\frac{93}{99}\frac{92}{98}\frac{91}{97}\cdots$$ and stop when it gets below $0.10.$ Alternatively I guess you could try using Stirling's approximation.

Comment: $100 \times \left(1- 0.1^{1/(100-94)}\right)$ will give you an approximation

Comment: @user14111: you will soon find terms start to cancel so you end up with something like $\frac{68 \times 67\times 66 \times 65 \times 64 \times 63}{100 \times 99 \times 98 \times 97 \times 96 \times 95}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$${94 \choose x} \left/ {100 \choose x}\right. = \frac{94!}{x! (94-x)!} \cdot \frac{x! (100 - x)!}{100!} = \frac{(95-x)\cdot (96-x) \cdots (100-x)}{95\cdot 96 \cdots 100}$$
$$ = \left(1 - \frac{x}{95}\right)\left(1 - \frac{x}{96}\right)\cdots\left(1 - \frac{x}{100}\right)$$
Now you can try integers nearby to the one that solves
$$\left(1 - \frac{x}{100}\right)^6 = 0.1$$
You only need to find a treshold because the function is monotonic. It's better to do this numerically. I found integers $x \geq 32$.

Comment: You could play with this python function:  ```def f(x):
   return (1-x/95)*(1-x/96)*(1-x/97)*(1-x/98)*(1-x/99)*(1-x/100)
```

Comment: Many thanks!  The final answer $x \geq 32$ is correct according to my workflow.